# NiFi - How can i change ReplacementValue on ReplaceText?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using ExecuteSQL,SplitAvro,ConvertAvroToJSON,EvaluateJsonPath,ReplaceText,ExecuteSQL.

I am trying to replace the content in the flowfile using replaceText processor.

Now, i can replace like this. -> INSERT INTO values (${id},'${name}') . ReplaceText process send excute sql like this :

INSERT into x values(1,'xx')

INSERT into x values(2,'yy')

INSERT into x values(3,'zz')

I'm sending INSERT query for each line.

But i want to send executesql process like this

INSERT INTO x values (1,'xx'),(2,'yy'),(3,'zz')

Comment: replace lines with `,(${id},'${name}')`, then use another replaceText to replace first coma with `INSERT INTO x values `

Comment: I'm using split avro so i have many queue. How can be possible many ,(${id},'${name}') out and just one insert into query?

Comment: merge all files back into one so you will have `,(1,'xx'),(2,'yy'),(3,'zz')` then apply ReplaceText to replace only first coma

Comment: I just started using nifi. Can you tell me the process order i should use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure it's the best approach but you could do this:

```python
SplitAvro           # i guess you are splitting the records here (here you should get fragment.* attributes)
ConvertAvroToJSON   # converting each record to json
EvaluateJsonPath    # getting id,name values from json
ReplaceText         # (${id}, '${name}')
MergeContent        # merge rows back to single file with header and delimiter
   Binary Concatenation
   Header = Insert into X values
   Demarcator = ,
ExecuteSQL
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it won't generate exactly the SQL you're looking for, take a look at ConvertRecord and/or JoltTransformRecord -> PutDatabaseRecord. The former is used to get each of your Avro records into the form you want (`id`, `name`), and PutDatabaseRecord will use a PreparedStatement in batches to send the records to the database. It might not be quite as efficient as a single INSERT, but should be much more efficient than a Split -> Convert -> ExecuteSQL with separate INSERTs per FlowFile.

To truly get the SQL you want, you'll likely need a scripted processor such as InvokeScriptedProcessor with a RecordReader, I have a [blog post](https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2019/04/record-processing-with.html) on the subject.